# Statement about the gradient

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f \in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^n).$
If there exists $u \in S^{n-1}$ such that
$$\nabla f(x) \cdot u \geq 0 \quad\forall x\in \mathbb R^n,$$
then $f(u) \geq f(0)$.
How to prove this statement?

Comment: Just for clarification: What is $ S^{n-1} $ ?

Comment: @Imago, it is the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$. At least this is standard notation and makes perfect sense in the question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, yes true, I was just not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $h(t)=f(tu)$.
Check that these hold:

- This is a $C^1$ function.
- $h'(t)=u\cdot\nabla f(tu)$.
- $h(0)=f(0)$ and $h(1)=f(u)$.

Can you make progress working with this function $h$?
The problem is now one dimensional.
If you need help with this problem with $h$, let me know.

Comment: Going by Joonas Ilmavirta's answer: 
I would first observe: $ h'(t) = \nabla f(tu) \ge 0 \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $
Therefore $ h(1) > h(0) $ since $h$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: @Imago, that is indeed what I wanted to leave for the OP to figure out. Two typos in your comment: the formula for $h'$ is missing the inner product with $u$ and we can have $h(1)=h(0)$.

Comment: Also note that we do not need $f\in C^1,$ just that $f$ is differentiable everywhere.